# Laravel 5.2 model binding attribute obfuscate

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using `Form::model` to creates form for a model with Laravel 5.2. In the [documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding) they wrote:

> When you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field value. So, for example, for a text input named `email`, the user model's `email` attribute would be set as the value

But in that way, all the model fields name will be public. So the client will be able to see the exactly name of the fields of my internal program (even in the database), and I want to prevent that.
In the internal code, I want to use the real field's name, but to hide them from the client.

Is there any way to still using model binding but obfuscate the fields name?

Answer (score 0):

You could create dynamic attributes on the model using the

```
protected $appends = ['foo'];
```

property. Then you can access these attributes via the following convention:

```
 public function getFooAttribute() {}
```